# Using 9-test or 11-test to find digit x in 52817*3212146 = 169655x15282

Tags: elementary-number-theory

David Burton Elementary Number Theory Revised Printing question 4.3.5(a) is as follows:

Using the 9-test or 11-test, find the missing digits in the calculations below:

$(52817 * 3212146) = 169655x15282$

I can tell the number of the right isn't divisible by 9 or 11 since
5+2+8+1+7 = 23 and 3+2+1+2+1+4+6=19 are both not a multiple of 9
while
5-2+8-1+7=17 and 3-2+1-2+1-4+6=3 are both not a multiple of 11
so neither of the factors of 169655x15282 have 9 or 11 as factors.

Thus, $1+6+9+6+5+5+x+1+5+2+8+2 \not \equiv 0$ (mod 9)
and $1-6+9-6+5-5+x-1+5-2+8-2 \not \equiv 0$ (mod 11)

so $x \ne 4$ and $x \ne 5$

Now, if I simply multiply 52817 by 3212146, I can see that $x = 9$ but I'm not sure how to get there from what I have.

How might I bridge this gap or is this just a typo in the text? Later editions seem to have altered the numbers involved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $52817 \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ and $3212146 \equiv 3 \pmod {11}$. And then by "utilising this" you get...

Comment: for some reason, that makes it clear. I'll answer this below.

Comment: Also note that $\gcd(9,11)=1$

Comment: I don't know yet how to combine congruences with different modulus. Probably coming up soon in this chapter.

Answer (score 0):

$52817 \equiv 6$ (mod 11) and $3212146 \equiv 3$ (mod 11)

$\implies$ $52817 * 321216 \equiv 6*3 \equiv 7$ (mod 11)

$\implies$ $169655x15282 - 7 = 11k$ for some integer k

$\implies$ $169655x15275 = 11k$ for some integer k

$\implies$ $1-6+9-6+5-5+x-1+5-2+7-7 \equiv 0$ (mod 11)

$\implies$ $2+x \equiv 0$ (mod 11)

Since $0 \le x \le 9$, $x = 9$